# How to access HDMI out port on Virtual Box Virtual machine?

Tags: android, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I was wondering if we  can access HDMI out on virtual box Virtual machine. Is there any way to achieve that.I have researched a lot on internet regarding this but I have not been able to find any thing useful so far. Any ideas will be really appreciated.

Thanks inadvance

Comment: You should ask Virtual Box questions on [Super User](http://superuser.com/). They are usually off-topic here. See the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) for details.

Comment: @jww: I asked the same question there as well but did not get any answer there as well..